# How do I convert an SQL Server SMALLDATETIME to a Unix timestamp?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, timestamp, smalldatetime

How do I convert an SQL Server SMALLDATETIME to Unix Timestamp?

date was stored as  CAST(0x96040474 AS SmallDateTime) in MS Access DB.  Data was dumped to SQL and I'm looking to convert those times to Unix Timestamps for MySQL.

Thanks
AO

Comment: Could you please refine your question?  A unix file timestamp? What particular format do you want?  BTW, I assume this is MS SQL you're asking about?

Comment: It was MS SQL -- but it was dumped out.  And I'm importing into MySQL.

Comment: I have alot of records that have a date that looks like this CAST(0x96040474 AS SmallDateTime) and no way to convert it to a unix timestamp.

Comment: Why is Access relevant? I see no reason for the tag.

Answer (score 1):

select datediff(ss, '1/1/1970', your_date_here)

e.g.

select datediff(ss, '1/1/1970', cast('1/1/1989' as smalldatetime))

Answer (score 0):

From *SQL Server 2005 Books Online*, "Transact SQL Reference"

> The Database Engine stores `smalldatetime` values as two 2-byte integers. The first 2 bytes store the number of days after January 1, 1900. The other 2 bytes store the number of minutes since midnight.

So it looks like you need to do some splitting of the hex values into two integers and convert from a 1900/01/01 base date to a 1970/01/01 base date, then take the other integer as integral minutes past midnight.

Comment: Ken -- can you convert a couple based on your formula above?  I can cross reference the dates to see if they come out right.  

0x96040474
0x9A9C03C0

Thanks
AO

Comment: CAST(0x9A9C03C0 AS SmallDateTime) and 


CAST(0x96040474 AS SmallDateTime)

Answer (score 0):

PHP's strtotime() function will take a smalldatetime as an argument.